# PostgreSQL - Count Function

Tags: postgresql

I've got two Tables Called Manu and Cars

```
Manufacturer      |      Employees      |      id
Toyota            |       102346        |       1
Subaru            |       284608        |       2
Kia               |       268244        |       3
Suzuki            |       228624        |       4
```

The second table Cars

```
Car      |      id
Corolla  |      1
camry    |      1
alto     |      4 
vitara   |      4
forester |      2
impreza  |      2
 xv      |      2
 cerato  |      3
 celica  |      1
```

Now the table Cars references back to table Manu through Id

Im trying to return manufacturers that have produced 2 or more models of cars.

So far what I have tried is

```
Select m.id, m.manufacturer 
from Manu m
inner join Cars n on m.id = n.id
group by m.id having count(n.id) >= 2;
```

it tells me that column m.id must appear in group by clause or be used in an aggregate function. Very confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First we'll get the number of cars by manufacturer:

```
SELECT id,COUNT(id) FROM cars GROUP BY id;
```

Next, we'll use that data to get the manufacturers that make more than two models:

```
SELECT s.id,s.count,m.manufacturer FROM 
    (SELECT id,COUNT(id) FROM cars GROUP BY id) s 
    JOIN manu m USING (id) WHERE s.count >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have already give the answer. just you didnt group by m.manufactorer;

```
Select m.id, m.manufactorer
from Manu  m
inner join Cars n using(id)
group by m.id,m.manufactorer 
having count(*) >= 2;
```